# Protecting carbon bike frame after a small chip?

Tags: frames, carbon

My bike frame is carbon and it recently got a small chip. It's about the size of a pinky fingernail in size. Should I do anything to treat the chip to help prevent it from getting worse?

---

Here's a photo of the chip, hopefully this helps narrow things down.

[image: Image of chip![][1]]

Comment: A picture of the chip would be useful (if its just in the frame's clear coat, which it sounds like it probably is, just apply some clear nail polish). Also, http://jimlangley.com/articles/caring-for-carbon-fiber-bicycles-and-components-pg71.htm

Answer (score 2):

The effects of the chip depend a bit on "how much" was chipped away. Generally it is always better to seal the chip. I have seen water getting under the protective paint/carbon layer and the area slowly expanding.

If the chip is small I've heard people using nailpolish with good success. For anything a bit bigger, I would probably bring it into a carbon repair place and have them check that the carbon is still structurally sound. They can also repair the chip more professionally.